# ¿Como obtener el username con el que estoy logeado spring?

Tags: java, spring

Hola me estoy conectando a un servidor de prueba que tiene cierta información, después de logearme debo registrar en mi base de datos a la persona que se acaba de logear (el login siempre se realiza con el servidor de pruebas y no con mi base de datos, el username seria "documento").
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para realizar este login utilizo el componente.

```
@Component

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    try {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        String url = "http://siaweb.xxxx.xxx.co/prueba.php";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("documento", name);
        map.add("clave", password);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        if (obj.optString("documento") != "" && obj.optString("documento") != null) {
            String documento = obj.optString("documento");
            Optional<Usuario> usuarioOpt = usuarioRepository.findById("documento");

            if (!usuarioOpt.isPresent()) {
                Usuario usuario;
                String nombreU = obj.getString("nombre");
                int tipo = obj.optInt("tipo");
                String tipod = obj.getString("tipodescripcion");
                usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setId(documento);
                usuario.setNombre(nombreU);
                usuario.setPerfil(tipo);
                usuario.setTipodescripcion(tipod);
                usuarioRepository.save(usuario);

            }

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, authorities);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

}
```

El SpringSecurity

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll().and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    
}

}
```

El problema es cuando intento mostrar o actualizar la información del usuario que se registró en la base de datos, para hacer esto en mi controller necesito enviarle el id del usuario el cual es el mismo documento y/o username que utilizó para logearme

```
@Controller
public class viewController {

@Autowired
UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

@GetMapping("")
public String mostrarDatos(Model modelo) {
    Optional<Usuario> usuarioOpt = this.usuarioRepository.findById("");
    usuario = usuarioOpt.get();
    modelo.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);
    return "home";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo puedes hacer usando *thymeleaf*

```
<div  sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <h3>Hola,  <span sec:authentication="name"></span></h3> 
</div>
```

Si lo quieres obtener desde el controller puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

auth.getName();
```

Saludos!!!

Comment: muchas gracias mihermanazo

Comment: No hay de que, puedes darle a la flecha de arriba porfa? Me ayudarías a ganar reputación

Comment: no me deja porque tengo poquita reputacion

Comment: :(, bueno no importa. Un abrazo crack ;)